# Duvida com Vraptor Download de Imagens

Tags: java, vraptor

Olâ pessoal estou com uma duvida quanto a função de Download do Vraptor, eu tenho um IMG no meu servidor e tento exibi-la no meu Aplicativo Mobile mas quando faço a requisição para o servido ele não me retorna uma resposta do tipo IMG (type = "image/jpg" não é erro na requisição quando eu faço o chamo o Werb service me retorna status 200.

Se alguém tiver ideia poderia me ajudar.

```
 @Get
public Download foto(String foto) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Gabriel\\Portifolio\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\upload\\"+foto);
    String contentType = "image/jpg";
    String filename = foto;

    return new FileDownload(file, contentType, filename);

}
```

Código na minha função para Download de imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Darlan Oliveira, sou novo aqui, mais acho que posso te ajudar. Em meu projeto fiz um Controller pra fazer o gerenciamento de minhas imagens e este é um código que fiz.

```
@Open
@Get
@Path("/formaPagamento")  
public Download imagemFormaPagamento(String id) {  
    File file = new File(NomenclaturaArquivo.getImagemFormaPagamento() + id);

    String contentType = "image/png";
    String filename = id + ".png";

    try {
        return new FileDownload(file, contentType, filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("erro: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

E eu chamo ela em minha JSP assim:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/imagem/formaPagamento?id=${f.id }'/>">
```

sendo que em meu controller eu uso uma anotação para definir como imagem.

```
@Controller
@Path("/imagem")
public class ImagemController {
```

A anotação @Open é uma que eu criei para deixar o código ser acessado sem necessidade de estar logado no sistema, então desconsidere.

Realmente não sei se te ajuda, mais talvez você esteja fazendo algo diferente. Estas são partes do meu código funcionando, passo a passo. Ali no NomenclaturaArquivo, é uma classe que possui constantes que levam as minhas pastas do servidor. Assim acho mais tranquilo de trabalhar e de fazer futuras modificações de caminhos, em vez de chumbar no código fonte. Claro que isso vai de programador para programador.

Também tive bastante problemas para encontrar minhas imagens na pasta.... Geralmente a chamada do JSP estava correta e somente meu arquivo não era encontrado, pois estava usando o linux. Eu fiz no caso uma classe simples main, tentando achar este arquivo e retornando um (FileNotFoundException) até achar a forma correta de encontrar minha imagem. Ai sim passei a rotina para o JSP. Assim acho que é mais fácil de testar, sem precisar executar no servidor.

Não sei se te ajudei, mais fica ai minha contribuição.